# Breaking change in previous major release

Tags: semantic-versioning

I am seeking guidance for the following scenario -

Assume that we have the following multiple production versions of a public API -

1.1.0

2.1.2

If a bug/defect was identified in the "1.1.0" version fixing which would introduce a breaking non-backward compatible change, how would the versioning need to be handled? Following semver, a breaking change would necessitate incrementing the major version - so "1.1.0" should become "2.0.0". However, we already have the next major version "2.1.2" live with its own changes.

Is it advisable to skip numbers between major version upgrades to accomodate for such scenarios? i.e. the next planned major version after "1.0.0" should have been "3.0.0"?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> so "1.1.0" should become "2.0.0"

Not true. Not only do you already have a 2.0.0, the [semver](https://semver.org/) spec doesn't require monotonicity. You can release it as 3.0.0 or 100.0.0. Normally however, this is where you would discontinue support for the 1.y.z series and encourage folks to upgrade to your existing 2.y.z.

Another option would be to merge the feature sets of 1.0.0 and 2.0.0 into 3.0.0.

ADDENDUM:

You made certain choices in the past, that affect the future evolution of your branded product, and your reputation as an organization. When you claim to be applying semantic versioning, you MUST not release a breaking change without bumping the major version number. The longer you adhere to the specified semantics, the more your customers will trust your claim.

You did not sign any contracts with a standards body in this case, but beyond that, none of us here at SO can advice you on your current legal obligations to your customers. It's up to you to decide at this point whether a strict adherence to semver is in the best interests of your customers or your organization.

Barring any contractual obligations between you and your customers, I would advice being as transparent with them as you possibly can. Explain your branding and versioning conundrum and rebrand your 1.y.z product, such that it can adhere to using semantic versioning. If you had product X, rename it X.Classic or some such.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying. The challenge we are likely to face is that clients on the 1.x.x series would be willing to accept only specific changes on top of their existing version. Asking them to consume 2.x.x or 3.x.x which are likely to include other breaking/non-breaking changes will be met with resistance due to the additional potential impact.

Comment: Either your branding or versioning strategy is flawed. If you have two substantially different products named `X 1.y.z` and `X 2.y.z`, and you are unwilling to discontinue service for the 1.y.z series when an important defect forces a breaking change, then you must drop any claims to adhering to semver and force a breaking change on your customers with a minor bump.